# Add breakpoints for network requests in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How do I manually perform each subsequent request in Chrome DevTools? I mean add a breakpoint after each request automatically. For example, I would like to get the first row in the table below, then click some button and get the second row and so on...

[image]

Comment: There is a feature request for this: crbug.com/1313861. Upvote if you think it's useful

Answer (score 4):

You can setup an event listener on XHR/Fetch calls, which will pause the execution of the code when the browser makes a network request.

**Notes:**

1. Click the Sources tab > Expand the XHR Breakpoints pane.
2. Click Add breakpoint. Enter the string which you want to break on. DevTools pauses when this string is present anywhere in an XHR's request URL.
3. Press Enter to confirm.

**More info:**
https://www.canidev.tools/debug-xhr-fetch-calls/chrome

[image]

Comment: This method makes many queries at a time before the first pause. I tested on this stackoverflow page.