# React Developer Tools in fault

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, react-devtools

I have a problem with React Developer Tools. When I refresh the page of my react app in Google, there is a bug that causes the page to not reappear, it spins endlessly. If I disable the React Developer Tools extension, it works perfectly. Using Firefox where I don't have an extension, it works perfectly.

Is the problem with Google or the React dev tools extension? I guess my app is clean, otherwise I would have the same problem on Firefox.
Thanks

Comment: It's quite impossible to help with this information. What spins endlessly? Are there any errors in the console? I'd bet there's a bug in your app that manifests when React Devtools does something, but of course it's possible that React Devtools is at fault too.

Comment: The page refresh runs unsuccessfully, there is no error in the console.

Comment: To restart, I have to close the tab and restart localhost:3000 in another tab.

Comment: What do you mean with "page refresh runs unsuccessfully"?

Comment: When I click the refresh or the F5 key, the little arrow spins infinitely and can't find the page.

Comment: My app use : redux, reactReduxToolKit, Axios, react-beautifull-dnd, universal-cookie

Comment: I finally found the solution, but I explain it badly. The requests were stuck on loading hook.js, I don't know where this request comes from, I just installed npm install hook.js and my app works perfectly. Here's to sharing.
If anyone knows why and how this request is issued, I'm interested.

Comment: You can use your browser's network inspector to break on network calls to given URLs to see the callstack. Anyway, I really don't believe installing a random [npm package that is downloaded only 5 times a week](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hook.js) is what actually fixed your issue.

Comment: You can hover over an underlined text in the "Initiator" column in the Network tab to see call the stack.
And for XHR, you can add breakpoints for "hook.js" in the "Sources" tab (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73115202/add-breakpoints-for-network-requests-in-chrome-devtools )